# basic differntial equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

im starting a course in regular differential equation,
first HW for the year, so this should be basic, and im not sure how to approach it.
$$y\prime=\frac{cy}{x}f\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)$$

Im supposed to find a method of solution for this type of problems.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Artem's hint $\frac{y}{x^2}=z$, or $y=x^2z$. Differentiating both sides w.r.t. x and substituting this into the given eqn. we get a separable equation in z: $x^2z'+2xz=y'=cxzf(z)\Rightarrow xz'=-2z+czf(z)$. Rewrieting this we have
$\int\frac{dz}{z\big(-2+cf(z)\big)}=\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln x+c$.

Comment: thank you very much! 
please note that you had a calculate error with the minus when you wrote $-czf(z)$ it should be a $+$        $\ \ \ \ $

Comment: You're welcome. I have edited as you have indicated.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Make a substitution 
$$
\frac{y(x)}{x^2}=z(x)
$$

Comment: thanks alot for your support, but as i said this is the first homework, so i need abit more.. 
the real help i would like is to see a full-on solution..
with explanaition with why and how...

Comment: @eyal, full solutions are never good. Since you are just starting with the subject, the very best you can do is to spend time thinking and trying things.

Comment: Can the downvote be supplemented with a constructive comment?

Comment: @artem ok. got it! please edit your original answer - only then can i change the downvote to an upvote